# Docker-compose not starting all services

Tags: docker-compose

I have two services (mongo and mongo-express) in the docker-compose file. When I try to start the file docker creates only one container (mongo). Then if I start second container (mongo-express) manually, then it works fine.

*.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4.15
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

mongo-express logs

```
mongo-express    | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express    | ------------------------
mongo-express    |
mongo-express    |
mongo-express    | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express    | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express    | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.3:27017
mongo-express    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express    |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express    | }]
mongo-express    |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
mongo-express    |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express    |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
mongo-express    |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
mongo-express    |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express    |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
mongo-express    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
mongo-express    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express    |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express    |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express    | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongo-express    | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `mongodb` started too late than `mongo-express`. Try adding `depends_on`, but I recommend looking at [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to check if `mongodb` is started.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4.15
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```